# What is the type of the phrase "to success"

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases

The textbook says that **To success** is an adjective phrase but it seems like an infinitive to me.

I'm confused whether it is a noun or an infinitive?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text.  Type out the sentences you're interested in.

Comment: Checking answers is not a service that I provide.  I'll try to answer the question, but I'll not correct your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no verb "success".  The verb is "succeed".

Success is a noun. So "to success" is a prepositional phrase.  And prepositional phrases can be used to modify nouns, as in the metaphorical idiom "the road to success"